# Safety of running without clutch start sensor Ford Ranger 95 STX SuperCab

Tags: ford, clutch, sensor, ranger

The clutch start sensor on my Ford Ranger 95 STX SuperCab gave out and I bypassed it, for now. It's becoming very hard to find a replacement that can be imported to Brazil, so is there a problem with running without it for the long term, if I can't find the part?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/ford,1995,ranger,4.0l+v6,1138047,electrical-switch+&+relay,clutch+pedal+position+/+starter+safety+switch,16665

Comment: Rockauto rocks! But the shipping is almost the price of the item, and I pay 80% tax over the price PLUS shipping to get any automotive parts imported to Brazil...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it by "clutch start sensor" you are meaning the neutral safety switch, the sensor which won't allow you to start the vehicle unless the clutch is depressed or the vehicle is in neutral? If so, this will cause your vehicle no issues to run without it. This is meant as a safety item to prevent the vehicle from moving if you leave it in gear while starting. As long as you account for it and prevent the vehicle from being in gear or depressing the clutch at startup, you should have absolutely no issues.

Comment: I don't see how bypassing any safety device is acceptable advice.

Comment: @user71659 - The advice I'm giving is for the car, not for the user. Besides, there are plenty of places throughout the world which don't even use a neutral safety switch.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I have the habit of starting the truck with the clutch depressed anyway, but as I said, it has been quite problematic to get the neutral safety switch in Brazil for such an old Ranger.